# How can I limit Google Places Android API to return only gyms?

Tags: android, google-places-api

When using the Google Places Android API, the API normally gets the user's location and returns a list of nearby places.  How can I limit this list to only gyms?  While the solution for web is readily available, I can't seem to find how to do it for Android.

This is my current code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

    try {
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> types = new ArrayList<>();
    types.add(Places.TYPE_GYM);
    for(PlaceLikelihood likelihood : result) {
        if(hasMatchingType(result.getPlace(), types)) {
            //This is a gym, do whatever you need to here
        }
    }
}


    private boolean hasMatchingType (Place place, List < Integer > allowedTypes){
        List<Integer> types = place.getPlaceTypes();
        for (int type : types) {
            if (allowedTypes.contains(type)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

[image: Example output]

Comment: Please refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve